# CSS - Arranging blocks with <div> to get metro style themes

Tags: css, html

Before CSS gurus jump down my throat, I do know how have blocks arranged in CSS the way I want. What I'm specifically looking for is a way to have blocks resize when resizing browser windows (More importantly on tablets changing from landscape to portrait)

http://jsfiddle.net/UUN3x/2/

```
 <div style="width: 700px; height: 220px;">
   <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: red; height: 210px; width:210px;">   </div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: 10px; background-color: blue; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: 120px; background-color: green; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: 230px; background-color: black; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: 340px; background-color: yellow; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 110px; background-color: brown; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: 120px; margin-top: 110px; background-color: aqua; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: 230px; margin-top: 110px; background-color: orange; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: 340px; margin-top: 110px; background-color: silver; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div style="width: 700px; height: 220px;">
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; background-color:red; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: 110px; background-color: blue; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: 220px; background-color: green; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: 330px; background-color: brown; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: 440px; background-color: aqua; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: 550px; background-color: orange; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-top: 110px; background-color:red; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: 110px; margin-top: 110px; background-color: blue; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: 220px; margin-top: 110px; background-color: green; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: 330px; margin-top: 110px; background-color: brown; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: 440px; margin-top: 110px; background-color: aqua; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: 550px; margin-top: 110px; background-color: orange; height: 100px; width:100px;"></div>
</div>
```

So when I re-size the browser, blocks should move nicely and remain within browser window.

I'm using absolute here for positioning which I'm sure is the cause for this. But using relative and fixed, I wasn't able to get divs to align nicely in the first place :|

Any help/suggestion/direction is appreciated :)

Comment: Have you ever heard of css classes?

Comment: You want to do a search for css media queries, this will solve your issue.

Comment: Yeah if you use a class that is 20 less times you have to write `display: inline-block; position: absolute;`. As aaronmallen stated, media queries will do the trick for you.

Comment: That code upset me more than it should have. http://jsfiddle.net/UUN3x/5/

Comment: I hope I didn't make anyone lose their faith in humanity! I was just testing with 2-3 blocks and just kept on adding the other blocks. No way in hell this goes in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many js library that can help you with what are you trying to achieve. For example see this:

-[Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html)
-[Wookmark](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin)
-[Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Comment: Thing of beauty! I was just looking to use css but this works just the way i needed it to!

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilt the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/UUN3x/6/ this is how I'd do it.

This is just using math, you don't need `media queries` to answer your question. Change all the static numbers to percentages. Use `javascript` to set any vertical numbers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densityDpi=device-dpi">
    <style type="text/css">
    .boxes {
        width:100%; /* 700px */;
        height:auto; /* 220px */;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .box {
        display: inline-block;
        float:left;
        border-color:transparent white white transparent;
        border-width:0 10px 10px 0; /* this will be set/updated with js */
        border-style:none solid solid none;
    }
    .box-small {
        height:100px; /* this will be set with js or you can use a resized image */
        width:14.285%; /* 100px/700px */
    }
    .box-big {
        height:210px; /* this will be set with js or you can use a resized img */
        width:30%; /* 210/700 */
    }
    .box-red {
        background-color: red;
    }
    .box-blue {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    .box-green {
        background-color: green;
    }
    .box-black {
        background-color: black;
    }
    .box-yellow {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    .box-brown {
        background-color: brown;
    }
    .box-aqua {
        background-color: aqua;
    }
    .box-orange {
        background-color: orange;
    }
    .box-silver {
        background-color: silver;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box box-big box-red"></div>
            <div class="box box-small box-blue"></div>
            <div class="box box-small box-green"></div>
            <div class="box box-small box-black"></div>
            <div class="box box-small box-yellow"></div>
            <div class="box box-small box-brown"></div>
            <div class="box box-small box-aqua"></div>
            <div class="box box-small box-orange"></div>
            <div class="box box-small box-silver"></div>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box box-small box-red"></div>
            <div class="box box-small box-blue"></div>
            <div class="box box-small box-green"></div>
            <div class="box box-small box-brown"></div>
            <div class="box box-small box-aqua"></div>
            <div class="box box-small box-orange"></div>
            <div class="box box-small box-red"></div>
            <div class="box box-small box-blue"></div>
            <div class="box box-small box-green"></div>
            <div class="box box-small box-brown"></div>
            <div class="box box-small box-aqua"></div>
            <div class="box box-small box-orange"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        (function(){
            var boxSizing = function(){
                $(".box").each(function(){
                    var $this = $(this),
                            thisWidth = $this.css("width"),
                            borderWidth = (10/700 * parseInt($(".boxes").css("width"))) + "px";
                    console.log(borderWidth);
                    $this.css({"height":thisWidth, "border-width":"0 " + borderWidth + " " + borderWidth + " 0"});
                });
            }
            $(window).resize(boxSizing);
            boxSizing();
        })();
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```